# Scrapy: Setting up pipline - if url does not contain

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am trying to setup a pipeline filter where if the url does not contain '133199', I would like to drop item.
Unfortunately, I don't think my code is working.

```
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class FilterWordsPipeline(object):

    category_filter = ['133199']
    def cat_filter(self, item, spider):
        for word in self.category_filter:
            if word in unicode(item['url']).lower():
                raise DropItem("Is not in the: %s" % category)
            else:
                return item
```

Comment: What is not working?  Please post a description of the error.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.20/topics/item-pipeline.html):

> Writing your own item pipeline is easy. Each item pipeline component is a single Python class that must implement the following method:
>
> process_item(item, spider)

Just rename your "cat_filter" function to "process_item".
And make sure you have something like `ITEM_PIPELINES = { 'myproject.pipelines.FilterWordsPipeline': 500 }` in you settings.py file.

And also, you are dropping the items in which the url does contain '133199' and letting the items which the url does NOT contain '133199'.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you just missing a not in the 'if word in' check? Should be 'if word not in'.